# Запуск java приложения

Tags: java

возможно задаю очень глупый вопрос, но я ни разу не сталкивался с java раньше.
Как можно запустить это приложение? https://github.com/matthewhampton/Gemsbok

Comment: Пожалуйста , добалните ваш вопрос вашими попытками

Comment: @shalor1k, я пробовал запустить через tomcat. Но там нужно указать путь до war файла, но его нет в проекте. Возможно его как то нужно собрать, но я не нашел как это сделать. У меня вообще есть сомнения, что этот проект можно запустить, он очень старый. В одном из файлов указан tomcat 6, а его уже и скачать нельзя

Answer (score 1):

1. Его надо собрать. В качестве сборщика используется система сборки [ant](https://ant.apache.org/)
2. Далее надо взять веб сервер, который имеет встроенный сервлет контейнер, что-то типа Tomcat или JBoss
3. Далее запустив сервер надо развернуть на нем (deploy) полученный в ходе шага #1 сборку (JAR/WAR/EAR) файл

Как то так.

**Update**

В идеале, судя по настройкам билд файла `ant` все должно работать если запустить с командной строки (при наличии установленного [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)):

```
ant -buildfile build.xml build-and-deploy-all-war-files-to-tomcat
```

Но это в идеале :)

Comment: war собирается таргетом `build-all-in-one-war`

Comment: К сожалению не смог скомпилировать. Выдает ошибки типа 
'[javac] error: error reading /home/petr/Gemsbok-master/platform/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik.jar;java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 63: file:/hom/petr/Gemsbok-master/platform/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/\'